# Const declarations are not supported in strict mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webkit, ionic2

I am working on an ionic2 angular2 project that requires push notifications on ios. After installing the apn package (`npm install apn`) and including the apn package in my component, I keep getting the `Unexpected keyword const` error as shown below. Note, commenting out the instantiation line of apn.Provider() prevents this error.

Did anyone else run in to this issue? I have been fiddling around for quite some time and appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

home.ts

```
import * as apn from 'apn';
```

...

```
var options = {
      token: {
        key: "path/to/key.p8",
        keyId: "T0K3NK3Y1D",
        teamId: "T34M1Ds",
      },
      production: false,
    };
    var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
```

Error:

```
 396157   error    SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode., http://192.168.0.3:8100/build/main.js, Line: 135427
```

main.js (note, this file is auto-generated, so I cannot directly make changes here)

```
"use strict";
"use strict";

const APNKey = __webpack_require__(715);
const oids = __webpack_require__(900);
```

Comment: It is Node package. Besides the fact that it may be unworkable outside of Node environment, it was obviously written in ES6 - because Node supports it. You have omitted the details on build process, but you certainly need to transpile this module with Babel and/or think twice if using Node package in client side app is really in your plans.

Comment: thanks for the reply. is the APN package designed for the server? is running it on the client side incorrect? I basically need to Push notifications and was trying to follow the example for APN, as it is a requirement for ios push notifications

Comment: also what would i need to do to transpile w babel? i never used it

Comment: For starters, provide the details on how you build the app in your question. If it's Webpack, then its config should be specified. Babel can be used for ES6 files the same way as Typescript is used for TS.

Comment: Yes, it was designed for server. I've not used it but it looks like chances that it can be used on client side are not so good.